# Web2py - Setting Title & Meta Tags in Views

Tags: web2py

I'm attempting to set unique title and meta tags for each of my views. If I set tags in the following way at the top of my view...

```
{{
response.title='My Product view'
response.meta.keywords='phones,calls,smartphone'
response.meta.description='This is a phone seller site made with web2py'
response.meta.author='me'
}}

{{extend 'layout.html'}}
```

...the tags appear to be set properly, with exception to the title tag. If I inspect the head, the title tag does not appear.

If I set the tags in the following way with or without the head tag...

```
<head>
<title>My Product view</title>
<meta name="description" content='This is a phone seller site made with web2py'>
<meta name="keywords" content='phones,calls,smartphone'>
<meta name="author" content='me'>
</head> 

{{extend 'layout.html'}}
```

...the tags appear to work properly, including the title tag, but all of my form inputs lose 20 pixels in height.

Does anyone know why I may be experiencing this? What is the best way to set these items in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do not put any HTML before `{{extend 'layout.html'}}`, as anything before the `extend` will be inserted before the beginning of the HTML in 'layout.html', which itself begins with the opening `<html>` and `<head>` tags (so, your example inserts an entire `<head>` section before the opening `<html>` tag of the document, which then includes another `<head>` section).

Setting `response.title` as you have should work fine. However, your 'layout.html' must include something like the following in the `<head>` section:

```
<title>{{=response.title}}</title>
```

The 'layout.html' of the scaffolding app includes a [similar line](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/applications/welcome/views/layout.html#L10) (with a fallback in case there is no `response.title`).

Comment: I removed the <title></title> tag from layout.html, and replaced it with the raw application name, which caused the title tag to disappear. I did that so the application name that I render on each page wouldn't change as I modified response.title. My mistake was that I assumed response.title functioned like response.meta, in that if response.meta is not set in layout, but subsequently set in the view, then the tag is created in <head>.

Comment: Is it common for Google's Structured Data Testing Tool not to recognize the <title> and <meta> tags if you set them dynamically in the view (as we've done here in the first example, correcting for the removal of <title> in layout.html)?

Comment: You need to submit the final rendered HTML to that tool, not the Python template.

Comment: The tool fetches a url, then validates the markup. The markup exists in the rendered document, but the tool doesn't recognize the title or metatags-description (e.g. they do not appear in custom search result filters). I don't believe Google follows keyword meta tags any more, so I'm not really worried about that one. https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

Comment: You can also paste in the HTML. Anyway, there's nothing special about the title in web2py pages -- it's just some text between <title></title>. If you created the identical HTML by hand, Google wouldn't know the difference.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think the title element is relevant to "structured data". In this context, "structured data" refers to HTML markup in microdata, RDFa, or JSON-LD format.